# Find text between two tags and replace it with the uppercase version of the same text

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

I am writing code that gives me proper nouns in a sentence in uppercase. I am using an NER tagger for that to get tags like PERSON and LOCATION. I want my code to output the text between the tags in uppercase. I am doing it the following way but its not working:

```
    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("<PERSON>(.+?)</PERSON>|<LOCATION>(.+?)</LOCATION>").matcher(NER);
        while(m1.find())
         { String newDecapTitle = m1.appendReplacement(sb, decapTitle.get(m1.group().toUppercase()));
........
}
```

Here sb is a string buffer.
To give you an example:

> James murray went to Los angeles

gets parsed as

```
<PERSON>James murray</PERSON> went to <LOCATION>Los angeles</LOCATION>
```

and I want my output to be -

> James Murray went to Los Angeles

.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving it the whole pattern, try giving it a `m1.group(1)` (which is James murray) and `m1.group(2)` (which is Los angeles). Or you can do another regex and strip all the tags from your final result (PERSON and LOCATION - those are tags, stack strips them as well).

Comment: But I am not sure how many tags a sentence will have so how do I account for that?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of future proofing, I have considered that you may use tags in the future that may be different to just `<PERSON>` and `<LOCATION>`. You can do the following to capture words between the tags that are of the form `<tag></tag>`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String in = "<PERSON>James murray</PERSON> went to <LOCATION>Los angeles</LOCATION>";

    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile(">(.*?)<").matcher(in);

    while (m1.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m1.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("matched text: "+ m1.group(i));
        }
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
matched text: James murray
matched text:  went to 
matched text: Los angeles
```

You can use this to do whatever you want with the captured words.

Another solution is to use a non-capturing group to do something like this (untested):

```
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("(?:<PERSON>|<\\/PERSON>|<LOCATION>|<\\/LOCATION>)?([\\w ]+)").matcher(in);
```

This will find specifically the tags and capture the groups between them. But I would recommend the first way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is very useful! I am using the latter method but what I really want to do is make sure the Murray and Angeles are capitalized and appended back to the sentence. I have to iterate over maybe 1000s of sentences which may have proper nounns decapitalized.

Comment: @serendipity you will most likely have to iterate through the words to check case on them, unless you can find a way to do that in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with jsoup and apache.commons.lang WordUtils

Example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ExtractInfo  {

    public static void main (String [] args) { 
        String html = "<PERSON>James murray</PERSON> went to <LOCATION>Los angeles</LOCATION>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements es = doc.select("person,location");
        for(Element e : es){
           String eText = e.text();
           e.text(replace(eText));
        }
        System.out.println(doc.text());
   }
   public static String replace(String str){
       return WordUtils.capitalize(str);
   }
}
```

//prints "James Murray went to Los Angeles"